# System.Data.DuplicateNameException: A column named 'Item' already belongs to this DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable

I have an extension method to turn an IEnumerable into a data table and it is throwing this exception. `System.Data.DuplicateNameException: A column named 'Item' already belongs to this DataTable.` What's confusing is that there is not a column named 'Item' in this table, or at least there shouldn't be because the SqlTable it was created from does not have an 'Item' column.

```
public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items)
{
    var dataTable = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);

    var props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

    foreach (var prop in props)
    {
        dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType);
    }

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        var values = new object[props.Length];
        for (var i = 0; i < props.Length; i++)
        {
            values[i] = props[i].GetValue(item, null);
        }

        dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
    }

    return dataTable;
}
```

This extention method has been working except until now when I use it with a method that takes in a sql table and makes it a datatable, then turns the data table into and IEnumerable to update one column and then uses the extenstion method on the Ienumerable to turn it back into a datatable.

```
var strSqlQuery = "Select * FROM " + strTableName; 

var dataTable = Database.CreateDataTableFromDatabaseTable(strSqlQuery);
var ocRows = dataTable.AsEnumerable(); // turn the data table into an enumerable we can sqlbulkcopy dump later

foreach (var dataRow in ocRows)
{
    if (dataRow[4].ToString().Contains("COMPLETED")) continue;
    // Generate and Save Needed Hashes for this Node
    // This is the algorithm to generate the hash
    var md5Hash = MD5.Create();
    var profileId = Database.GetProfileIdByEndPage(dataRow[3].ToString(), false);
    var endPageId = Database.GetEndPageId(navigationProfileId);
    var strValuesForObjectHash = string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataRow[6].ToString()) // if the "id" is null or empty use xpath
        ? endPageId + "," + dataRow[7]  // use the xpath for the object hash, not the "id"
        : endPageId + "," + dataRow[6]; // if the id has a value use the id for the object hash
    var currentObjectHash = strValuesForObjectHash.GetMd5Hash(md5Hash);
    dataRow[1] = currentObjectHash;
}
```

I tried in the extension method to check if the column had already been added but then got 
`System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException: Parameter count mismatch.`

```
foreach (var prop in props)
{
    if (dataTable.Columns.Contains(prop.Name))
    dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType);
}
```

How can I use the DataTable as enumerable to update the one column for each row and make it into a DataTable again?

Comment: As an side, why do you use reflection to create a `DataTable` from a database query instead of using `DataAdapter.Fill(table)`? Also, there is already one available for this purpose(`CopyToDataTable` with any type): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096(v=vs.110).aspx